# Proving that $\sf Add$$(\aleph_\omega , 1)$ collapses cardinals $\leq \aleph_\omega$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, forcing

First, let me fix some notation.

$\sf Fn$$(I, J, \kappa) = $ the poset of all partial functions $p$ such that $|p| < \kappa$, dom$(p) \subseteq I$ and rng$(p) \subseteq J$.
$\sf Add$$(\kappa, \lambda) = \sf Fn$$(\lambda \times \kappa, 2, \kappa)$

The question reads: "Show that forcing with  $\sf Add$$(\aleph_\omega , 1)$ collapses all cardinals $\aleph_\alpha$ for $\alpha \leq \omega$ to $\omega$.
**Hint**: For each $n \in \omega$ find a way of coding a surjection of $\omega$ onto $\omega_n$ into the generic subset of $\aleph_\omega$.  Use a density argument."

I have been trying this for a while and cannot get it.  I know there is a problem very similar to this in Kunen, but his hint does not help me either.  I know that instead of the poset $\sf Fn$$(\aleph_\omega \times 1, 2, \aleph_\omega)$ we could consider the poset $\sf Fn$$(\aleph_\omega \times \omega_\omega, 2, \aleph_\omega)$ since they will give rise to the same generic extension, but I'm still not sure how the code the surjections.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\Gamma\subset \omega_\omega$ denote the generic subset. Working in $V[G]$, we define $g:\omega\to\omega_\omega$ as follows: $$g(n)=\begin{cases} 0, &\text{if } \operatorname{ot}(\Gamma\cap(\omega_{n+1}\setminus \omega_n))<\omega_n \\ 
\alpha, &\text{if }\operatorname{ot}(\Gamma\cap(\omega_{n+1}\setminus \omega_n))=\omega_n+\alpha. \end{cases}$$

It is not hard to see that $g$ is onto. ($\operatorname{ot}(X)$ means order-type).

Edit: I'm adding a proof that $g$ is onto.

For each $\alpha<\omega_\omega$, define 
$$D_\alpha=\{p\in \operatorname{Add}(\aleph_\omega,1): \exists n\in\omega\ (\omega_{n+1}\setminus \omega_n)\subseteq \operatorname{dom}(p)\wedge \operatorname{ot}[p^{-1}(1)\cap (\omega_{n+1}\setminus \omega_n)]=\omega_n+\alpha\}$$

Observe that if $D_\alpha$ is dense then $\alpha$ is in the range of $g$. So it suffices to show that $D_\alpha$ is dense for every $\alpha\in\omega_\omega$.
 Fix $\alpha\in\omega_\omega$ and $p\in \operatorname{Add}(\aleph_\omega,1)$. Now, pick $n\in \omega$ so  that $\alpha<\omega_n$ and $|p|<\omega_n$.
 Let $\xi=\sup(\operatorname{dom}(p)\cap (\omega_{n+1}\setminus \omega_n))+1$. Note that $\xi\in\omega_{n+1}$ as 
$|\operatorname{dom}(p)∩(\omega_{n+1}\setminus\omega_n)|<\omega_n$
 and $\omega_{n+1}$ is regular.

Now define an extension $q$ of $p$ belonging to $D_\alpha$ as follows:
$$\operatorname{dom}(q):=\operatorname{dom}(p)\cup (\omega_{n+1}\setminus\omega_n)$$
We just need to define $q$ in $(\omega_{n+1}\setminus(\omega_n\cup \operatorname{dom}(p))$
$$q(\beta)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }\> \beta<\xi \wedge \beta\notin \operatorname{dom}(p)\\ 1 & \text{if }\> \beta\in [\xi,\xi+\omega_n+\alpha)\\ 0 & \text{if }\>\beta\in[\xi+\omega_n+\alpha,\omega_{n+1})\end{cases}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new to forcing, do you think you could expand a little?  So $\Gamma = \{ \alpha \mid \exists p \in G (p(\alpha) = 1) \}$ (this is in $V[G]$ correct?)?  And then for each $\gamma < \omega_\omega$ I can write $\gamma = \omega_n + \alpha$ for some $n \in \omega$.  Also, for $\gamma < \omega_\omega$ $D_\gamma := \{ p \in \mathbb{P} \mid p(\gamma) = 1 \}$ is dense.  Am I going down the right path? This could just all be wrong . . .

Comment: @RyanSullivant You are on the right track but let me expand my answer.

Comment: Great, thank you very much!

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks again.